# Real world inference problem for forecast probabilities

Tags: forecasting, inference

The set up:

Me and a friend set up a website which employees of a small company (<10 people) submit forecasts for the next month's revenue of different sections of the business, and also an estimate for the business as a whole. These estimates consist of them assigning a probability to several bins. (e.g., for a branch of the business based in California, they might forecast a 15% chance of monthly revenue being below £10k, and 40% chance of it being between £10-15k, a 30% chance of being £15-20k and a 15% chance of being over £20k)

We then can measure retrospectively how good these forecasts are, e.g. with a brier score or similar.

The problem:

We then want to do some inference. Given the forecasts for the next month, produce a sensible estimate. My current thinking is as follows:

- For a point estimate, we could take a simple average, perhaps weighted by past accuracy (although so far we only have one month's data).
- For an error estimate, we would probably want to assume the underlying forecast of each individual follows a distribution, that individual forecasts are independent, and then aggregate them. E.g. for estimating the revenue earned by the Californian branch in the example above, they are estimating a vector of probabilities, and we have some measure of how correct or incorrect they were in the past

For this second part, I am not sure what distribution assumption would be appropriate - I have only come across a limited class of parametric distributions in the statistics I have covered so far, or what might be a sensible way to update the weights with more forecasts.

Secondly, at first we will only have a very small set of data, although that will be increasing over time.

(For reference: my background is more in mathematics than in statistics, but have taken an elementary statistics course, largely in normal linear models, and some hypothesis testing. It is only in the third year of our course that we take less elementary statistics courses)

**Edit**: In light of Stephen Kolassa's comment, instead of a distribution overlay, what might be better is a reasonable metric of the uncertainty of the forecast, rather than some meta distribution of the forecast

Comment: If your "input" forecasts are binned, then the simplest way to obtain a consensus density forecast would be to just use the same bins. I would be wary of overlaying a distribution, which smacks of conjuring information out of thin air. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: so that was my initial thought. However, I would also like to get some measure of the uncertainty of the forecast? (which will hopefully decrease with more data!)

Comment: You mean the uncertainty of a probabilistic forecast? That could in principle be done, but it does sound a little meta to me (and probably incomprehensible to most consumers of forecasts, who typically already have a hard time understanding density forecasts as such).

Comment: yes. in particular, when at present we have 6 people forecasting, with one month's data, this should presumably have greater uncertainty than several month's data with 12 people

Comment: but that second point is a good one. it might be a bit meta and incomprehensible

Comment: i suppose then what might be more helpful that a distribution overlay is if there are any sensible metrics of uncertainty for this kind of problem. It would be helpful to the company people to have some idea of how the forecasts are improving when they engage with it

Comment: Hm. I'm all for helping people see how they are improving things. I would say that your best bet would be to show how the average expectation forecast will (very probably) be better than each separate expectation forecast. I would also assume the combined density forecast to be better than the separate ones, but even *assessing* density forecasts (via proper scoring rules) is very unintuitive, and any improvement in a score will be hard for people to wrap their heads around.

Comment: Incidentally, weighting by past performance may improve the consensus forecast. Or it may not. See [Claeskens et al. (2016, *IJF*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.12.005). I would very much recommend you compare your weighted combination to an unweighted one.

Comment: ok thank you! on weighting forecasting probabilities I have read some of Philip Tetlock's papers on superforecasting, which did do weightings based on past performance for the IARPA competitions which seemed to work quite effectively (but they had a very large sample size and large number of questions)

Comment: I don't this is what you mean, but there is a view among some who run times series (probably purely based on experience not theory) that a weighting multiple different forecast (forecast methods) generates better results. Some of the things you combine may have different probabilities although that has not been raised in what I looked at. That suggest to me that more forecast reduce rather than increase uncertainty. I don't think it is possible to even know uncertainty in time series....given realities such as structural changes over time ....